# How to assign texture to a loaded OBJ file in java3d

Tags: java, 3d, textures, java-3d

I have a java 3d application and this application I load an OBJ file into my scene. How can I assign a texture (a jpg file) to this model?
To be more precise, when I want to assign texture to a primitive java object (e.g. sphere) I use the following:

```
Sphere sphere = new Sphere(Radius, Primflags, Appearance);
```

However, when loading and adding an obj file I do:

```
Scene scene = getSceneFromFile("OBJ file");
myBranchGroup = scene.getSceneGroup();
```

And in second case, I can find no way of assigning the texture. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use a program that you made the obj file or were you can load the file. Paint it, then export that file. Then add this code to it outside any methods

```
static TextureLoader loader = new TextureLoader("C:\\Users\\Sawyera\\Desktop\\Paint Layer 1.jpg",
"RGP", new Container());
static Texture texture = loader.getTexture();
```

Then

```
texture.setBoundaryModeS(Texture.WRAP);
texture.setBoundaryModeT(Texture.WRAP);
texture.setBoundaryColor(new Color4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
TextureAttributes texAttr = new TextureAttributes();
texAttr.setTextureMode(TextureAttributes.MODULATE);
Appearance ap = new Appearance();
ap.setTexture(texture);
ap.setTextureAttributes(texAttr);
 int primflags = Primitive.GENERATE_NORMALS
    + Primitive.GENERATE_TEXTURE_COORDS;
    ObjectFile loader = new ObjectFile(ObjectFile.RESIZE);
```

Then add this before you assign the model to the scene. Assuming the 3D model varrible is called model

```
model.setAppearance(ap);
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you need to get the `Shape3D` node you want to apply the texture to (calling `setAppearance(...)`) from your branch group, e.g. by using `getChild(index)` etc. Note that you might to iterate recursively through the children, since the branch group you get might actually contain other groups, so you might find the shapes further down the group tree.

Alternatively you should be able to add an `AlternateAppearance` object to the branch group.